# GIM Mechanism Software (Kinematics / Analysis / Synthesis)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, software, linkage, kinematics

I've recently discovered a very awesome software tool for the synthesis and analysis of mechanisms.  The tool is called GIM, from Faculty of Engineering in Bilbao, Department of Mechanical Engineering, University of the Basque Country (UPV/EHU)  "The software is intended for educational purposes, in particular destined to the field of kinematic analysis, motion simulation and synthesis of planar mechanisms" as well as for the "static analysis of mechanical structures."  I'm doing some personal dynamic art work with six bar linkages (not for profit) so I think I'm okay here.

- [Link to download GIM software](http://www.ehu.eus/compmech/software/)
- [Four Bar Tutorial Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xMHisJR384)
- [Synthesis Sample Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DkrrYgSLMc)

I will say the interface wasn't totally intuitive.. after a few minutes in the users guide I was able to figure out the double click thing.  (Duh!  Read the messages on the bottom bar.)

I do have one issue that is driving me crazy.  I'm actually trying to easily compare different design alternatives. I'd just like to display coupler point output path, but I can't figure out how to do that.

[image: four bar mechanism with motion paths displayed]

Has anybody else used this tool?  Anybody know the secret to just showing a single output path?

Oh, and yes I'm aware of the [www.saltire.com software](http://www.saltire.com/HTML5/Mechanisms/4%20Bar%20Linkage.html) and that would work for displaying output in a nice format, but I won't have the synthesis and full analysis tools available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it took me way too long to figure this out.  I'm thinking this is just not a very intuitive interface.  Here's the fix for anybody else who makes it here. Click #1, Click #2 (carefully!), then check the box at #3.

[image: 4 bar display output path]